# Run-TIme error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error --- Merging Cells with same value

Tags: excel, vba, merge

I am trying to run this code so that it will merge the cells with the same values. But keep having this error appear every time that I try to run through it step by step. Does anyone know why I am having this error? Any feedback is appreciated.

```
Sub MergeSameCells()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim rng As Range

MergeCells:

For Each rng In Selection

   If rng.Value = rng.Offset(1, 0).Value And rng.Value <> "" Then
       Range(rng, rng.Offset(1, 0)).Merge
       Range(rng, rng.Offset(1, 0)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
       Range(rng, rng.Offset(1, 0)).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    GoTo MergeCells
   End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What's `selection`?

Comment: @findwindow it's a built-in it refers to the currently selected range.

Comment: If a range is already merged and you're trying to affect an already merged range, you're going to get a 1004.  I assume this error first occurs once you've merged?

Comment: @Warcupine lol I mean what's in selection.

Comment: @Cyril Yes. I it is unmerged and I am still getting this error.

Comment: Uh your edit triggers Cyril's comment?

Comment: @Warcupine Just number values

Comment: I can not repro this, running fine for me.

Comment: @Warcupine probably because your selection is valid.

Comment: I have figured it out. Thank you for the help

Comment: @Austin Hlinka What does that mean? What help are you talking about? Your code should work as it was... Just using `DisplayAlerts` to not be asked about merging with two values.

Comment: Voting to close as not reproducible.  In trying to code, it worked for me, where I set-up mock data using numbers 1-15; I used contiguous and non-contiguous ranges in my testing, multiple columns, etc.

Comment: The only way I was able to force a 1004 was replacing the line `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` with `Application.DisplayAlerts = True`.  I get an immediate pop-up for "Merging cells only keeps the upper-left value and discards other values", where if you press `Cancel` you get `RTE1004`.  This gives an invalid range, which ties back to FindWindow's comment.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce this error from the same code by having my data in a table (selected data, insert -> table). Removing the table (design tab -> convert to range) made it work right away.